# How Mocha determines nesting level?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, dsl

Currently I'm trying to understand how BDD DSL works in Mocha and I'm stuck. I'd like this approach and want to apply this.

For example, the following test:

```js
describe('foo', function(){
    describe('bar', function(){
        it('should be something')
    });
});
```

will produce output:

```
foo
  bar
    - should be something


0 passing (4ms)
1 pending
```

Question: how invocation of global function `describe` in nested block determined as nested? I looked at source code, but can't handle the main idea right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha keeps track of these things in Suites, as you can see from the [source](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/56e3e7f0c82e40e1b39d5cabe4eab19b615f0bc0/lib/interfaces/bdd.js#L71)

```
/**
 * Describe a "suite" with the given `title`
 * and callback `fn` containing nested suites
 * and/or tests.
 */

context.describe = context.context = function(title, fn){
  var suite = Suite.create(suites[0], title);
  suite.file = file;
  suites.unshift(suite);
  fn.call(suite);
  suites.shift();
  return suite;
};
```

To simplify things a bit, for each `describe`, Mocha creates a new suite.  Suites can contain other suites.

For your example, Mocha creates the `foo` suite, which then contains the `bar` suite, which contains the `should be something` test.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by a global tree data structure.

When you call a **describe**, mocha adds a node, when you call **it**, mocha adds a leaf.

When the root **describe** call returns, the tree is complete and mocha traverses the nodes executing the leafs one by one.